# pod template file not created while running helm install command on helm charts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have created a basic pod definition in my values.yaml file. However, `helm install <name> <path to charts dir>` doesn't create the "pod.yaml" in the templates directory. My understanding is that once you define the default values in the "values.yaml", the templates files gets created. Did I misunderstood? Do I have to add this "pod.yaml" manually?
Here is my pod definition. Thanks!

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: xxyy
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: app-name
image:
  repository: imagename
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  repository: ""
  # Overrides the image tag whose default is the chart appVersion.
  tag: ""

replicaCount: 1
imagePullSecrets: []
```

Answer (score 2):

`helm install` *reads* the files in the `templates` directory, applies the templating system, and sends the resulting YAML to the Kubernetes cluster; but it never *writes* a YAML file anywhere.

If you want to see the YAML that your templates would send to the cluster, [`helm template`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_template/) will print it out.  This is always based on the files that you wrote in the `templates` directory, though; Helm won't create the YAML on its own.

If you created your chart by running [`helm create`](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_create/) you will get a basic template that contains (among other things) a Deployment spec in `templates/deployment.yaml`.  You need to edit that file if it doesn't meet your needs.  (Directly working with bare Pods isn't usually what you want: you can't scale them and you generally can't modify them once they're created.)

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation and the clarification. `helm template` - a useful command that you mentioned here; it is useful to see the contents that is sent to kubernetes cluster. Thanks!